# How to intercept a http request done from Angular in a cordova Android plugin?

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, webview

I need to get the http headers of the response of an http request done with Angular on a Cordova app. I would like to keep a reference, on native side, of the token I get in the header.

I can only seem to find references to the method [shouldInterceptRequest](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest%28android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest%29) of the class WebviewClient. I need to pass a WebViewClient to the WebView. The problem is I can't get the WebView!

I tried several ways to get the webview from the CordovaActivy, but anything works. For instance if I do the following the app crashes.

```
public class MyActivity extends CordovaActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        loadUrl(launchUrl);
        WebView v = (WebView) this.appView.getView();
        v.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(final WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {

                return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request);
            }
            /*
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }
            */
        });
    }

}
```

Is there a way to get the headers in the plugin before they are read by javascript?

Comment: Did you found a solution?